# Recreate Git Branch without 1 commit

Tags: git

In a huge project that I work on and is using git there is a team that has been working for a huge feature for 3 months. In the 2nd month of that period one developer somehow managed to create one commit in the feature branch that has all files staged with no changes at all.

This causes a huge problem when we are trying to merge this feature branch into the main one.

Is there a way to recreate all 3 months of commits without that 1 bad commit ?

Comment: git rebase -i HEAD~n. Where n is one commit behind the commit you want to drop. Drop the commit. Later do git rebase <main_branch> before merging to the main branch.

Comment: The phrase *one commit in the feature branch that has all files staged with no changes at all* makes no sense: *staged*, in Git, means "in the index". Commits don't have an index. Commits are snapshots, and each snapshot has *all* the files. One generally compares a snapshot to its parent commit's snapshot to see "what changed". If nothing changed, the resulting commit is sometimes called "empty", but an empty commit is harmless, so there's nothing to worry about and it creates no actual problem. Hence if there *is* a problem, this description isn't quite right.

Answer (score 1):

Use [git-revert](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-revert):

```
git revert <errantcommithash>
```

This will undo whatever happened in your errant commit and commit those changes as a new commit.

Comment: It will “undo” using a new commit. This might be troublesome if you merge into another branch where you intend to keep the changes.

Answer (score 0):

The safest way is to do

```
$ git revert <commit>
```

where `<commit>` is the SHA1 hash of the problematic commit.

If you want to remove the commit entirely from the history, then you can use `git rebase`. If `feature` is the branch with the work then do the following:

```
$ git checkout feature
$ git rebase --onto <commit>~ <commit>
```

Note that this rewrites the entire history from the commit until the present. This means that every developer must now fetch the `feature` branch and reset to it rather than doing a `git pull`:

```
$ git checkout feature
$ git fetch origin feature
$ git reset --hard origin/feature
```

Comment: Why is this the safest way?

Comment: @evolutionxbox `git revert` creates a new commit that reverses the changes from the given commit. All developers can just `git pull` the branch and be up to date immediately. However, `git rebase` rewrites the history of the branch and requires each developer performs the last three steps in my answer. If any developer does a `git pull` instead, the original problematic commit remains in the history as well as duplicates of every change since then as both the original sequence of commits and the new sequence of commits created by the rebase operation.